# How to turn on my irrigation system

Tags: plumbing, sprinkler-system

I moved into a house that was a foreclosure but has an irrigation system. There was no one around to show me how to set everything up. I know where the control box is and have read the instructions well enough (I believe) to test the heads but nothing comes out. I have gone out to the box outside in the lawn where the valves are and they all seem to be open. I assume the problem is that there is some master water shut off valve to the system that I have not found. I'd rather not spend $100 to have someone come out to just turn a valve if I can help it. Any thoughts? It is a rainbird system if that helps but I don't feel that is relevant in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing to check: is there (or was there) a well?  If your sprinkler system is attached to a well, then this is the first thing to check.  Make sure it's on and operating correctly.

If it's not attached to a well, then it's just a matter of tracing the pipes, possibly from each end.  Locate the main shutoff in the house and any lines running to unknown locations, particularly back outside.  Make sure all valves are open.  Then from outside, trace the line running back into the house and check if there are any access panels in the path that could be hiding a valve.

Finally, just an obvious check, check your breakers and make sure the system doesn't have a rain switch that has been activated.

Comment: @B Mitch sort of mentioned this but if your sprinkler system is fed by your own well, check that the circuit breaker for the well is on (it will have its own breaker).  One of the items for winterizing the system is to shut off the well and cut off the breaker to make sure it does not accidentally turn on.

Comment: I am flagging this question as correct. The issue was the well where my water meter is also has a valve to turn on/off the sprinkler system. I didn't see it because my well is always full of water. I had pumped out a lot of the water but not enough apparently. Thanks for all your help. Working now!